# How to make mdframed aware on odd/even page?

Tags: mdframed

For theorems and alike I use `mdframed` package. So far I use solutions collected here on SE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{box}{% common style
    topline=false, bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    linewidth=2pt,
    backgroundcolor=none,
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={%
                  fill=teal!40, fill opacity=0.25}}},
    frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{black},
    splittopskip=1mm,
    frametitlebelowskip=0mm,
}
% Example
\mdtheorem[style=box,linecolor=teal!70
           ]{example}{Example}[chapter]%section

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
    \lipsum[2]    
\begin{example}[cross correlation]
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\newpage
    \lipsum[1-2]    
\begin{example}[cross correlation]
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Now I like to define mdframed (nonbreakable) box which will be aware, if it is on odd or on even page, for example, that left line would be always in outer side of a page. So far I try the following:

- define `\mdfdefinestyle{box-L}{... rightline=false, ...}` and `\mdfdefinestyle{box-R}{... leftline=false ...}`
- select one of those boxes according if the `example` is on odd or even page

The letter I try to accomplish with the following code:

```
\mdtheorem[%
    \label{example:\thechapter.\theexample},
    \ifodd\pageref{example:\thechapter.\theexample}
  style=box-L
    \else
  style=box-R
    \fi,      
  linecolor=teal!70
            ]{example}{Example}[chapter]%section
```

Unfortunately, this my (naive) approach doesn't work. I receive error:

`Use of \\mdframed doesn't mathch its definition.`

Is there a way to accomplish may wish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the `settings=...` key might help here.

`rightline` and `leftline` are keys that trigger the `mdf@rightline` and `mdf@leftline` bool variables. Using

```
settings={\ifodd\value{page}\booltrue{mdf@leftline}\boolfalse{mdf@rightline}\else\boolfalse{mdf@leftline}\booltrue{mdf@rightline}\fi}
```

should provide the relevant 'mapping'. The `settings` code is executed as a hook at the start of `mdframed`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{box}{% common style
    topline=false, bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    linewidth=2pt,
    backgroundcolor=none,
    settings={\ifodd\value{page}\booltrue{mdf@leftline}\boolfalse{mdf@rightline}\else\boolfalse{mdf@leftline}\booltrue{mdf@rightline}\fi},
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={%
                  fill=teal!40, fill opacity=0.25}}},
    frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{black},
    splittopskip=1mm,
    frametitlebelowskip=0mm,
}
\makeatother
% Example
\mdtheorem[style=box,linecolor=teal!70
           ]{example}{Example}[chapter]%section

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
    \lipsum[2]    
\begin{example}[cross correlation]
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\newpage
    \lipsum[1-2]    
\begin{example}[cross correlation]
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Its work as I wish! Thank you very much! Now I can ask for further help: how to manage positions of box title. I must confess, that I'm lost in `mdframed` documentation ... all examples in it doesn't work. Seems I encounter some error in copying them to my editor (WinEdit).

Comment: The solution use `\value{page}` for indication if box is on odd page. This would work in normal circumstances, however I'm afraid that in large documet this can fail. I sow, that for more reliable solution is suggested to use `\pageref` of box position. Is it possible to adopt your solution to this?

Comment: @Zarko: It might be possible, I would use `\getpagerefnumber` then, because you need something to be expandable (which is not the case for `\pageref`.) You might have a look on `tcolorbox`, which has support for `even/odd` page, as far as I know